# Creating large word comments in CSS stylesheets out of hashtag symbols?

Tags: css, comments, stylesheet

I'm working on a project where the previous developer made section headers in their CSS stylesheets that look like large words generated from hashtag symbols. I need to add a new section to his extensive stylesheets and I'm wondering if anyone has seen a generator that creates these? Or is he making these from scratch?

Here is a screenshot of what they look like:

[image]

Comment: on linux and unix there is a utility called `banner` which generates such text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A quick Google search for "generate ascii text banner online" provides [several](http://www.bagill.com/ascii-sig.php) [different](http://www.desmoulins.fr/index_us.php?pg=scripts!online!asciiart) [sites](http://www.network-science.de/ascii/) that will do this for you.  (A bit of experimentation demonstrates that you probably want to choose the "banner" font.)

Comment: Thanks! I tried several searches but didn't know this was called ASCII text. That helps a lot. This generator works great for anyone else searching for this: http://patorjk.com/software/taag/#p=display&h=3&v=0&c=c%2B%2B&f=Banner3&t=Word